# Wortart von "w"-Fragewörtern in Kontext

Tags: grammar

W-Fragewörter können je nach Kontext sowohl als Fragewort als auch als Relativpronomen fungieren.

> Wo wohnst du?
>
> Das ist die Stadt, wo Goethe mal durchgefahren ist.

Das erste Beispiel ist eindeutig ein Fragewört, das zweite ein Relativpronomen.
Doch was ist mit Fällen wie diesem

> Wofür du so dein Geld ausgibst, finde ich erstaunlich.

Es hat keinen Bezug ausserhalb des Nebensatzes, was dafür spricht, dass es KEIN Relativpronomen ist. Es steht ja relativ zu nix. Allerdings kann man ganz einfach ein "das" oder "wenig" oder so etwas ergänzen.

> Das, wofür du dein Geld ausgibst, finde ich erstaunlich.

Jetzt ist wieder ein Bezug da.

- Welche Wortarten ist/Funktion hat "wofür" in den jeweiligen Beispielen und warum?

Wenn es NICHT dieselbe ist...

- Ist es wirklich sinnvoll, ein und dasselbe Wort in ein und derselben Position, mit ein und derselben "Vibe" nur aufgrund einer Formalie zwei unterschiedlichen Funktionen zuzuordnen?

Comment: "Das ist die Stadt, durch die Goethe mal durchgefahren ist.", nicht *wo*. Aber "Das ist die Stelle, wo er sein Portemonnaie verloren hat" würde ich ertragen. :)

Comment: Relativpronomen, Konjunktionen und ähnliches müssen sich nicht auf vorangegangene Wörter beziehen! Im Deutschen kann man Haupt- und Nebensatz vertauschen. `Wofür du dein Geld ausgibst, finde ich erstaunlich.` = `Ich finde erstaunlich, wofür du dein Geld ausgibst.` Ganz eindeutig ist "wofür" ein Adverb (bzw. das, was du ein "Relativpronomen" nennst).

Comment: Würde ich sofort mitgehen, aber die offizielle Definition scheint das anders zu sehen: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativpronomen... ich weiß, das ist nicht offiziell ;)

Comment: Du meinst "an das der Relativsatz sich anschließt"?

Comment: @what....... ja

Comment: Nun ja, Wikipedia wird von Leuten wie dir und mir geschrieben. Vieles, was darin steht, ist falsch. In der Duden Grammatik und anderen Grammatiken gibt es Beispiele, in denen der Relativsatz vorne steht. "Wer zuerst kommt, mahlt zuerst."

Answer (score 4):

Laut [DWDS](http://dwds.de/?qu=wof%C3%BCr) ist `wofür` ein Pronominaladverb, das in deinem Beispiel relativisch (und nicht interrogativ) gebraucht wird. Das ist die Wortart.

Die Funktion im Satz ist die Einführung des Relativsatzes, der im Matrixsatz wiederum die Funktion eines Objektes hat. Im Nebensatz ist es ein Adverbial.

Der Bezug zum Matrixsatz besteht auf jeden Fall. Du kannst das Platzhalter-`das` gerne einfügen; es ist aber genauso möglich, es einfach wegzulassen.

Comment: Kann ein Relativsatz wirklich alleine, also ohne externen Bezug, ein Objekt konstituieren?

Comment: @Emanuel ??????

Comment: @what... "Was ich will, bist du" Toscho sagt, das "was ich will" ein Relativsatz ist. Aber er hat keinen Bezug im Containersatz, so wie zum Beispiel der "welcher"-Teil in  "Der Mann, welcher sein Fahrrad....".. macht das mehr Sinn?

Comment: Nee. "Was" bezieht sich doch auf "du": "Du bist, was ich will." Nur weil Haupt- und Nebensatz vertauscht sind, ändert sich doch der syntaktische Bezug nicht.

Comment: @what... ok, blödes Beispiel... "Sie sagt, was ich wissen will". Auf welches "Objekt" bezieht sich der was-Satz?

Comment: @Emanuel Der Nebensatz bezieht sich auf ein implizites `das`: „Du bist *das*, was ich will.“